# XMLHTTPrequest does not query the internal hosts file

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem with an XMLHTTPrequest.
I have a webserver A connected in vpn with another non-public webserver B where through nginx I transform http into https with reverse-proxy.
I put the ip of my webserver B in the hosts file of webserver A where the call is hosted.

When I make the call on the js file, however, this does not use the hosts file where the additional IP is set but the browser responding that it cannot reach the recipient with error 0.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: _The website's security certificate is not secure_

Comment: What do you mean by "*where the call is hosted*"? What JS file are you talking about?

Comment: `XMLHTTPrequest` is a client-side technology. It will respect the `hosts` file of the computer on which the browser runs, not the `hosts` file of some arbitrary webserver.

Comment: I read that as `XMLHttpPrequest`, I thought it was something new

Comment: Isn't it `XMLHTTPrequest` uses browser's cache? i.e. Edge doesn't obey changes in hosts file until it was restarted.

Comment: I don't really understand why the hosts file is involved. If webserver A is running an Nginx instance which is reverse proxying to webserver B then why is it not reverse proxying the xmlhttprequest as well?